# Se puede establecer fecha de caducidad para una pagina html?

Tags: asp.net, webservice, jquery-ui, cache, itextsharp

Gente tengo un html con un iframe dentro donde mediante jquery y un webservice cargo un comprobante en formato pdf, el problema radica en que el primer comprobante que deseo abrir lo hace bien, mientras que los siguientes siguen mostrando el primero. Supongo yo que es porque la pagina en cuestión se ha cacheado. Alguna otra sugerencia sino?

Funcion js que llama al webservice

```
function DescargarLiq() {
var url = "../paginas/ws.asmx/DescargarLiquidacion";
var archiv = window;
archiv.open("../paginas/Liquidacion.html", "PDF");
archiv.Ruta = url;
}
```

La funcion del WebService carga una imagen almacenada en el proyecto y mediante itextsharp la completa con los datos de la transaccion

Script dentro de la pagina Liquidacion.html

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Ruta = window.opener.Ruta;
        crarPDF();

        function crarPDF() {
            $('#iframepdf').attr('src', Ruta);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Este comportamiento lo controla el navegador, y lo hace principalmente en función de una serie de cabeceras HTTP que van asociadas en la *respuesta* que viene del servidor, y que le dan indicaciones de como gestionar la cache:

- `Pragma: no-cache` y `Cache-Control: no-cache`: Le indican al navegador que el archivo no se debe cachear, con lo cual siempre necesitará descargar la nueva versión al completo
- `Expires` indica un momento a partir del cual la copia cacheada se debe considerar inválida y descartada.
- `Cache-Control: max-age = 100` es similar, sólo que en vez de dar la fecha de expiración indica cuanto tiempo falta para ésta.
- `Last-Modified` indica cuando fue la última vez que se modificó el recurso en el servidor; si la fecha es posterior a la fecha del documento en la caché eso significa que el recurso ha cambiado y debe cargarse.

Todos estos valores se definen *en el servidor*, así que se debe modificar el código de éste para incluirlas.

Si solo puedes tocar el código de cliente, hay un pequeño "truco" fácil de probar: modificar la URL para que cada petición sea distinta, "engañando" de esa forma al navegador para que nunca acceda a la información cacheada.

Lo más sencillo suele ser añadir un parámetro "dummy" a la URL que vaya variando con cada petición; por ejemplo el tiempo del sistema:

```
var d = new Date();
var url = "../paginas/ws.asmx/DescargarLiquidacion?dummy=" + d.getTime();
```

De todas formas, si puedes modificar el servidor es mejor hacerlo allí porque a) solucionas el problema para todos los clientes que se conecten y b) dará menos problemas imprevistos.

Comment: Si quisiera especificar la caducidad desde el servidor, en que archivo deberia colocar las lineas que me comentas? estamos en IIS 6

Comment: Yo modificaría directamente el código que usas para generar el PDF, para incluir el header mediante el [`response`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.page.response(v=vs.110).aspx). Aquí hay un [pequeño ejemplo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/247404/how-to-modify-the-cache-control-http-header-when-you-use-iis) e indicaciones de como cambiar la configuración.